# List in shortsolution with xsim package

Tags: enumitem, xsim, texlive-2020

I am facing a compilation error while trying to use list environment (`itemize`, `enumerate`, etc) in `shortsolution` environment from the `xsim` package.

Here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xsim}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\xsimsetup{
  exercise/template = default,
  exercise/name = Aufgabe,
  solution/name = Lösung,
}

\DeclareExerciseProperty{shortsolution}

\newcommand*\printshortsolutions{%
  \begin{description}[leftmargin=3cm, style=sameline]
    \ForEachUsedExerciseByType{%
      \def\ExerciseType{##1}%
      \def\ExerciseID{##2}%
      \GetExercisePropertyT{shortsolution}%
        {%
          \item[Kurzlösung ##3] ####1%
        }%
    }%
  \end{description}
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{shortsolution}{b}
  {\SetExpandedExerciseProperty{shortsolution}{#1}}
  {}

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}
  This is the exercise
  \begin{shortsolution}
    Some text.
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item 
        Some more text.
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{shortsolution}
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
  The Solution
\end{solution}

\printshortsolutions

\printallsolutions

\end{document}
```

The error that I get is under TeXLive-2020.

```
! Use of \\enumerate doesn't match its definition.
\kernel@ifnextchar ...d@d =#1\def \reserved@a {#2}
                                                  \def \reserved@b {#3}\futu...
l.17   \end
           {shortsolution}
If you say, e.g., `\def\a1{...}', then you must always
put `1' after `\a', since control sequence names are
made up of letters only. The macro here has not been
followed by the required stuff, so I'm ignoring it.

! Illegal parameter number in definition of \l__exp_internal_tl.
<to be read again> 
                   1
l.17   \end
           {shortsolution}
You meant to type ## instead of #, right?
Or maybe a } was forgotten somewhere earlier, and things
are all screwed up? I'm going to assume that you meant ##.
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what output you expect but

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{shortsolution}{b}
  {\SetExpandedExerciseProperty{shortsolution}{#1}}
  {}
```

is documented as putting `#1` (the entire environment body here) through an `\edef`. You can not put fragile commands that take optional arguments in an edef without getting the type of weird internal error shown.

If you use

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{shortsolution}{b}
  {\SetExerciseProperty{shortsolution}{#1}}
  {}
```

Then it runs without error but I don't know if it is the output you need.